# Reshow loading when routing to same component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to achieve re-showing the loading indicator when routing to the same component.

html:

```
<div *ngIf="car$ | async as car; else loadingCar">
    Selected {{car}}
</div>

<ng-template #loadingCar>loading...</ng-template>

<div>
    <a routerLink="/cars/bmw">
        <button class="button">BMW</button>
    </a>

    <a routerLink="/cars/mercedes">
        <button class="button">Mercedes</button>
    </a>

    <a routerLink="/cars/audi">
        <button class="button">Audi</button>
    </a>

    <a routerLink="/cars/dacia">
        <button class="button">Dacia</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

ts

```
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {
  car$: Observable<string>;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.car$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => params.get("carBrand")),
      delay(2000)
    );
  }
}
```

This works the first time on the component, but once you click on another car it shows the previous one untill the delay is finished

I've made a Stackblitz for easy testing: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-url-params-subscription-nxe3cw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you'll see the loading again is if the `else` clause is triggered from the `*ngIf`. To do that, the `cars$` needs to get an `undefined` value.

Every time the `routeParams$` fires a new value, you need to set that `undefined` value. You can do this with the following code.

```js
const reset$ = new Subject<string>();

const data$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      tap(_ => reset$.next(undefined)),
      map(params => params.get("carBrand")),
      delay(2000)
);

this.car$ = merge(reset$, data$);
```

Updated blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-url-params-subscription-7hkady?file=src/app/cars/cars.component.ts